# How To Store User Data In A Database With A Changing Unique Identifier

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'll make it quick. I'm building an application that will relay heavily on Firebase, and especially the Real Time Database. It functions purely off of user input, which can obviously change and mutate. Essentially they will be sending what I'm calling `Bundles` to the database. They contain vital information about location, information, etc. So, the question, how can I structure the add script from my application so I can make sure that no duplicate data bundle names are generated, as it wouldn't be ideal at all. Using a users `UID` also wouldn't be ideal as that could lead to an immediate duplicate data if they send two `Bundles`. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by using the `push` function in the firebase documentation. This allows me to not only add the data bundle right into a list of other data bundles, but it also includes the server providing it with a unique key, thus removing all chances of duplicate bundle names occurring. You can check out the same docs by clicking [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/save-data)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use childByAutoId when creating the "bundle" node, This will create a node with a unique identifier.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data

Comment: If this solved your issue please make sure to mark the question as answered so it doesn't show on the "unanswered" tab :)

Comment: I can't accept my own answer for another few days, I will then